# how to send data to google analytics after every 10 minutes?

Tags: android, google-analytics

I don't want to send data to google-analytics instantly.I want to send data to it every 10 minutes periodically in android.How to achieve it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an app programmer but [according to the documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/d) data is sent only every 30 minutes in any case (not instantly).

Also it seems the the dispatch period is configurable in various ways:

```
// Set the dispatch period in seconds.
GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).setLocalDispatchPeriod(30);

//To set the dispatch period in the XML configuration file:
<integer name="ga_dispatchPeriod">30</integer>

Setting a zero or negative value will disable periodic dispatch, requiring that you use manual dispatch if you want to send any data to Google Analytics.

// Disable periodic dispatch by setting dispatch period to a value less than 1.
GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).setLocalDispatchPeriod(0);
```